# How can I create instance in Java when the factory method is default(non-static)

Tags: java

```
class X {                         
    private int i;           
    private X(){}             
    X factory(int v){  // d
            X r = new X();    
            r.i = v;          
            return r;         
    }                         
}
```

How can we create an instance of X using this part of codes? I can think of reflection but I think that is too complex. Is there any simpler way to figure out this problem? (Do not add static to factory method and do not delete the `private` key word of the constructor method).

Comment: You can add an instance to X to start things, or a nested class which calls the constructor. Or another factory method.

Comment: This is not really the factory pattern. You should rather have your `factory` method in a second class (same package for example)

Comment: So an instance of `X`, which has a private constructor, must exist to properly create an `X`? Without reflection, I don't see any other way aside from modifying the original class. This design is silly, anyway.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I thought the same thing, but this is not possible. How do you create the first seed `X` object?

Comment: If you can't change the code you need to use reflection or Unsafe or JNI (which all basically use reflection)

Comment: e.g. Unsafe.allocateInstance(X.class) creates an instance but you need to use reflection to get the Unsafe instance.

Answer (score 4):

You may use a builder inner class like this (`main` method added for testing purpose, of course you could call `X.Builder` from outside this class) :

```
class X {
    private int i;

    private X() {
    }

    public static class Builder {

        public static X factory(final int v) { // d
            X r = new X();
            r.i = v;
            return r;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        X myX = X.Builder.factory(42);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if we do not add a public method and code outside want to create an instance..? There is no difference between adding a nested public method or add the key word "static" right?..